# Using Subform for multiple field entries of one record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form with a subform. I would like to use the subform to not only enter child records, but also edit multiple fields on a single child record. The latter problem is where I'm stumped. Currently, I have the subform set up to open a separate form where I can enter the values for all the fields of a single record. Ideally, I would like to not have to go to a separate form to do this. Maybe I'm using the wrong control (the subform) to do this.

Along a similar note, are there any libraries of controls that can be installed to extend the default list of ms access control objects. How would I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A form and subform would look something like this: http://www.databasedev.co.uk/image/album_tracks_form_complete.gif What have you got?

Comment: I think that is exactly the type of thing I want. Can Track ID, Track No. and Track Length be set from that form. How did they do that?

Comment: Yes, they can. Here is something in the nature of a walk-through : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131211/create-form-to-add-records-in-multiple-tables Get back with any problems.

Comment: You could always design your subform as a bound form so it can Add/Edit/Delete while it is in DataSheet view.  @Remou helped me with the design on some of my other Questions, but eneded up taking a different path with my project.