# Multiple tables access database

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access-2007

I am very new to Access and I am working on a database and I need help coming up with a solution:

I am recording data from a bunch of asphalt laying crews. Each crew has a record with a field for production and equipment. Each crew has varying types of equipment and varying quantities of equipment. Therefore, I would need to create a new table for the type and quantity of equipment every time I enter a new record... can someone please help me come up with a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a new table for each record, you just need a properly set up table. Let us say:

```
Crews table
CrewID
Location
Etc

CrewMembers table
MemberID
Etc

CrewEquipment table
CrewID
EquipmentID
DateIn
DateOut
Etc

Equipment table
EquipmentID
Details
Etc
```

You might like to read http://r937.com/relational.html

With the above set-up, you can have a Crew form with subforms for members and equipment. You can get an idea from this [create form to add records in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131211/create-form-to-add-records-in-multiple-tables/12132196#12132196)

Answer (score 1):

Creating new table everytime is not solution, you should clear some RDBMS concept like normalization first. Create separate table for

```
crew member (which include crew member id, his name, salary/wages
List item per hour) equipments (which include equipments id, operation cost per hour etc) 
Shift (can be separated by date and shift time etc)
```

Then create proper relationship between tables and this way you can create proper relational database system. so finish some basic tutorial first then start development.