# Updating Tables In SQL Server 2005 Using Access 2010

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, updates

Very new to the world of advanced access and SQL Server 2005. I have now developed all my tables in SQL Server and added them to my blank database now in access using a ODBC connection. This topic is just for advice really, what would be the best way for me to create a form so that users within the company can input customer data without having to go onto SQL?

I have three tables 'Customer Table' 'Enquiry Source' & 'Admin Staff' - the 'Enquiry Source' & 'Admin Staff' consist of Enquiry Source ID, Enquiry Source Name, Admin Staff ID & Admin Staff Name which than have a link to the Customer Table.

When updating the tables myself in the SQL Side I use the ID's as integers but now I am in access I would like my users to be able to update these using the appropriate names on a list box. I have created a View in SQL and exported it to access but when I complete all the information and try and save the record it won't allow me to update multiple tables - which I understand is due to it being a View.

Is there an easier way of doing this so my teams can add new customers on the MS access front end system?

The Enquiry Sources are names of methods of referal: Newspaper, Recommendation, Google etc

The Admin Staff are names of employees creating the Customer.

Thanks Guys!
Callum

Answer (score 0):

Link the three tables or three simple views on the tables. Use the form wizard to create a form based on the customer table. Use the list box or combo box wizard to create a control based on each of the two look-up tables. See [create form to add records in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131211/create-form-to-add-records-in-multiple-tables/12132196#12132196) for some notes on how to use the wizards.