# Combox Requery after Update of Another Combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have 2 combo boxes one for Region and One for District (cboRR and cboDD). I am trying to get the cboDD combo box to show only the districts that are in the selected Region. What I have tried so far is adding in an AfterUpdate to the cboRR with a long IF statement with all the RRDD combinations and for the cboDD to have an OnClick Requery. I have tried various combinations of those and nothing so far is working. Are there any thoughts as to why I cannot get this to work?

The if statement for the AfterUpdate is:

```
Public Sub AfterUpdate()
If cboRR = "03" Then
cboDD = "03" & ";" & "12" & ";" & "13" & ";" & "30" & ";" & "46" & ";" & "55" & ";" & "56" & ";" & "76" & ";" & "86" & ";" & "92" & ";" & "95"
Else
cboDD = " "
End If
If cboRR = "07" Then
cboDD = "07" & ";" & "17" & ";" & "20" & ";" & "27" & ";" & "32" & ";" & "33" & ";" & "36" & ";" & "40" & ";" & "44" & ";" & "45" & ";" & "49" & ";" & "64"
Else
cboDD = " "
End If
If cboRR = "10" Then
cboDD = "17"
Else
cboDD = " "
End If
If cboRR = "12" Then
cboDD = "12" & ";" & "97"
Else
cboDD = " "
End If
If cboRR = "13" Then
cboDD = "02" & ";" & "04" & ";" & "21" & ";" & "41" & ";" & "45" & ";" & "46"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is not working? Is your AfterUpdate function not working? Are you firing it correctly on the change event?

Comment: Well the change is not working, I am not getting any error messages. I change the Region and I still have all the possible districts listed instead of just that regions districts.

Comment: Can you show how you are tying the Change event to the AfterUpdate function?

Comment: The code above is what I have set for the AfterUpdate in the cboRR combo box.

Comment: Are you sure AfterUpdate is getting called? If not, show how you are trying to call it.

Comment: Why are you not using tables with suitable columns?

Comment: Remou what do you mean?

Comment: @Attila It is getting called in the properties window

Comment: If you have a junction table that shows which regions are associated with which districts, it all gets much easier.

Comment: So just setup a regular table?

Comment: More or less, you need RegionId and DistrictId, values might be 07,17; 07, 20; 13; 02 and so on.

Comment: You might get some idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131211/create-form-to-add-records-in-multiple-tables/12132196#12132196

Answer (score -1):

Create a table that list all possible choices for your first combo box the regions. Then create a second table for your districts with a column that will have all applicable regions separated by the pipe symbol like so |01|02|.  Then create a query that looks at the value in your first combo with criteria set to:

```
Like "*|" & [Forms]![YourForm]![MyFirstComboBox] & "|*"
```

Comment: This is not a standard solution.

Comment: I am trying to make this as simple as possible, the less activity going on in the background the better. This is going to be used by people other than me. So the less there is to go wrong the easier their lives will be. I do appreciate the input and will look into this method.