# Updating a link table using Access form/SubForm

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a database which has the following structure:

PET(**Pet Id**, Name, Type, DoB, Allergies, etc)

OWNER(**Owner Id**, forename, Surname, DoB, Address, Etc)

REGISTERED(**Reg_ID**, *Pet_ID, Owner_ID*)

The reason for this structure being to remove a many to many relation whereby a pet may have several owners, the aim is that several people will be responsible for the animal in question.

My aim is to have one form that allows me to set up one owner and their pets at the same time (owner with a pet sub-form), the pet should automatically be added into the registration table at this point for that owner.

Other owners could be added through the registration table itself.

Any suggestions on how to do this in access? I'm trying to avoid simply stating that pets can only have a single owner.

Thanks

Comment: See if this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131211/create-form-to-add-records-in-multiple-tables/12132196#12132196 helps. However, you should consider that many pets have multiple owners.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll work through it today.